# Dropbox web vs desktop sync

Tags: dropbox, synchronization

I have a folder named MyFolder in the Web-Dropbox. I downloaded the desktop version of Dropbox and installed it. The Desktop-Dropbox folder contains a folder named MyFolder but its contents are not identical to the contents in the folder of the Web-Desktop.

What will happen?

1. Web-Dropbox will override Desktop's contents
2. Desktop-Dropbox will override Web's contents
3. Both files will remain at the new MyFolder folder both on web and on
   the desktop
4. Something else

Comment: Just wondering how come you have two different files of the same name in the different locations? One presumably was edited, copied, modified later than the other? - in which case it should "win". Are you suggesting you already had a "Dropbox" folder on your desktop at the time you installed the desktop application?

Comment: @w3d, precisely so:  I used DB on web and created a certain file structure there. Now I installed DB on my desktop and some folder names conflict. But as per AI E's answer this is not a conflict; DB will manage it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both folders will end up with the same contents. Whatever is on your desktop and not on the Web will be sync'd to the Web, and vice versa. If there are any files with identical filenames Dropbox will try to determine which is the one it should keep. I don't know the details of their algorithm but I would think they would keep the one with the newest timestamp. (Then again, Dropbox often gets very cautious if it can't tell and will keep both files with modified filenames to indicate a conflict.)

This would be really easy to test.